# I seem to have multiple accounts somehow (?)

Tags: support

Apologize in advance if this is a noob question.

Here on engineering.stackexchange.com (logged in via Google), I am known as GPS Pilot and my reputation is 21.

Then I logged into space.stackexchange.com via Google. There, I am known as user3358338, and my reputation is only 11.

Can I do something to link / consolidate these accounts?

Answer (score 3):

You actually only have one account. Reputation on the StackExchange network is on a per-site basis.

If you click on your avatar (top-right bar on the screen), you'll enter your [user profile page](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6188). There you'll see a link "Network profile" (top-right of the page, to the right of the Profile / Activity / Edit Profile and Settings tabs).

Clicking on that and then selecting the "accounts" tab will show [all the sites to which you belong on the StackExchange network](https://stackexchange.com/users/4090110/user3358338?tab=accounts).

Clicking on any of the sites will take you to your user profile page for that site. By random sampling, your user name seems to be "user3358338" everywhere but here.

If you wish to set this name for all sites, enter your user profile in any of them and click "Edit Profile and Settings". Set the name you wish to adopt for all sites and click "Save and copy changes to all public communities".